# What's the correct word to use here?

Tags: word-choice

> It is through their perspective ___ I show that English is hard.

What word is grammatical? Or is there another word I should use?

> It is through their perspective **that** I show that English is hard.
>
> It is through their perspective **whereby** I show that English is hard.

Comment: You don't necessarily need any word there.

Comment: It's just a typical context where the relativiser ***that*** is "optional".

Comment: **Whereby** is wrong after **through**.